# Where can I look up for the ntpd log?

Tags: ntpd

I didn't find any ntpd log file in /var/log. I am wondering where can I find those log files, thanks!

Comment: See also: https://serverfault.com/questions/359835/where-are-the-ntpd-log-file-located-and-how-can-we-configure-the-ntpd-log-file

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This may tell you if/where ntp activity is being logged:

```
grep log /etc/ntp.conf
```

You can also try:

```
ps auxww | grep '[n]tp'
```

Comment: And you can probably just grep for ntp in `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: @Phil: That's true as carson said in his answer, however the log file can be changed in the conf file or by using a command line parameter. That's why I suggested something that would lead to where that alternative might be.

Comment: Absolutely right Dennis.

Answer (score 12):

NTP doesn't normally generate many log messages nor have its own log file.   Log messages on my system are found in `/var/log/daemon.log`.

Statistics are found in the statistics dir (`/var/log/ntpstats` on my system). Presence of statistics files are controlled by the filegen options in your ntp.conf file.

Comment: A simple example for stats/logs generation can be found in https://serverfault.com/a/995110/86801.

Answer (score 3):

You should see them in /var/log/messages or wherever your syslog messages are going.

Comment: This is where my NTP logs are stored on Amazon Linux