# Where are the ntpd log file located, and how can we configure the ntpd log file path?

Tags: linux, logging, ntpd

I deal with that, ntpd as a daemon on my linux server by default configuring， but where should we look up the log file? Is there any log file normal, and if not , how can we configure that?

Answer (score 8):

ntpd logs basic messages to syslog by default, so where those logs go is dependent on your syslog configuration, but `/var/log/messages` and `/var/log/syslog` or common places to look.

ntpd can also generate statistics if `statsdir` is defined in `/etc/ntp.conf` and you have some `filegen` definitions.  [Here is the documentation for statsdir and filegen](http://doc.ntp.org/4.2.6p3/monopt.html).

Comment: I found that we can set the log file path by the options of "-l /path", and the default configure file is syslog.  http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~mills/ntp/html/ntpd.html

Comment: An example for stats/logs generation can be found at https://serverfault.com/a/995110/86801.

Answer (score 0):

By default `ntpd` uses the syslog mechanism, unless `logfile` is specified in the configuration file.

Despite of that the amount of log messages is configured using the `logconfig` directive in the configuration file.

Maybe you find the old [NTP FAQ entry "*6.1.4.1 How can I configure the amount of logging information?*"](http://doc.ntp.org/ntpfaq/ntp-s-config/#6141-how-can-i-configure-the-amount-of-logging-information) helpful.