# Where can I see ntpd working status (log or message)

Tags: ntp, ntpd, ntpdate

In my server the ntpd service is started but it does not seem to work.

I can find nothing according to this ( [Where are the ntpd log file located, and how can we configure the ntpd log file path?](https://serverfault.com/questions/359835/where-are-the-ntpd-log-file-located-and-how-can-we-configure-the-ntpd-log-file) ) and this ( [Where can I look up for the ntpd log?](https://serverfault.com/questions/225780/where-can-i-look-up-for-the-ntpd-log) ) :-(

According to MadHatter's suggestion (See [How can I synchronize system time with a NTP server continuously?](https://serverfault.com/questions/774227/how-can-i-synchronize-system-time-with-a-ntp-server-continuously) ), I listed some information in my server:

`ntpdate` returns:

```
2 May 21:47:55 ntpdate[47274]: the NTP socket is in use, exiting
```

`ntpq -c as` returns:

```
ind assID status  conf reach auth condition  last_event cnt
===========================================================
  1 22393  9614   yes   yes  none  sys.peer   reachable  1
  2 22394  9414   yes   yes  none  candidat   reachable  1
  3 22395  9414   yes   yes  none  candidat   reachable  1
```

`ntpq -c pe` returns:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
*time5.aliyun.co 10.137.38.86     2 u  157 1024  377   42.869    3.156   0.274
+time7.aliyun.co 10.137.38.86     2 u  402 1024  377   42.997    4.893   0.251
+ntp3.aliyun.com 10.137.38.86     2 u  276 1024  377   38.393    7.159   0.263
```

And my `ntp.conf` (# lines are not listed) is:

```
minpoll 4
maxpoll 8
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/drift
restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict -6 default kod nomodify notrap nopeer noquery
restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict -6 ::1
server ntp1.aliyun.com
server ntp2.aliyun.com
server ntp3.aliyun.com
includefile /etc/ntp/crypto/pw
keys /etc/ntp/keys
```

**UPDATE**

`ntpq -c rv` returns:

```
assID=0 status=0644 leap_none, sync_ntp, 4 events, event_peer/strat_chg,
version="ntpd 4.2.4p8@1.1612-o Tue Nov 29 00:09:12 UTC 2011 (1)",
processor="x86_64", system="Linux/2.6.32-220.4.1.el6.x86_64", leap=00,
stratum=3, precision=-20, rootdelay=42.918, rootdispersion=11.376,
peer=18777, refid=182.92.12.11,
reftime=dad1e8b1.6b42ba77  Mon, May  2 2016 22:54:41.418, poll=8,
clock=dad1e995.5771e298  Mon, May  2 2016 22:58:29.341, state=4,
offset=-0.578, frequency=23.898, jitter=1.845, noise=1.218,
stability=0.223, tai=0
```

p.s. This server is located in Chengdu, China (GMT+8)

Comment: Sorry, should have added a request for `ntpq -c rv` - since it looks very much as if you are sync'ed, which I wasn't expecting.

Comment: see update ....

Comment: `minpoll 4` and `maxpoll 8` are newly added since my previous question ( http://serverfault.com/questions/774227/how-can-i-synchronize-system-time-with-a-ntp-server-continuously ) . I don't know if they take effects.

Comment: Why do you think it isn't working?  What symptoms are you seeing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definitive statement is in your `ntpq -c rv` output, where it says

```
stratum=3
```

You are sync'ed; **`ntpd` *is* working**.  When your daemon reports a stratum that isn't 16, you know you are sync'ed.  In this case, `ntpq -c pe` tells you that your system peer (the one whose clock your daemon is currently following) is `time5.aliyun.com`, aka `ntp1.aliyun.com`.  Its stratum is 2, and yours is one greater, which is correct behaviour.

`ntpdate` returns the socket-in-use error because the socket *is* in use, as `ntpd` is running; once the daemon's running, you can't use `ntpdate` to shift the clock.  That is why `ntpdate` is normally run at startup, *before* the daemon starts.

Comment: There are [security risks](https://blog.gaborszathmari.me/2015/11/11/tricking-google-authenticator-totp-with-ntp/) with using ```ntpdate``` (in an automated fashion) that may apply.  Use of ```ntpdate``` should only be done by hand when you can verify that the resulting system time is sane when compared to the wall clock.

Comment: As the second part of the linked article notes, "*ntpd and ntpdate are vulnerable to MITM attacks*".  Configuring an NTP server (or servers) - whether to `ntpdate` **or** to `ntpd` - is trusting it not to lie about the time.  If knowing the correct time is important to you (say, you're a TOTP OATH validator), then you should choose the servers you decide to trust with some considerable care.

Comment: Or use either the ```key``` option for symmetric keys or the [auto-key public-key authentication option](http://www.ntp.org/ntpfaq/NTP-s-config-adv.htm) for ntpd.